# How do I install Dot Net Core on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, mono, .net

I am using Apricity OS (based on Arch Linux). I want to install Dot Net Core. What is the command for installing it by pacman.

Comment: You learn how to use [the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository)...

Comment: @jasonwryan If you know the exact way can you please tell me how to do it? I would still need to learn using AUR.

Comment: I linked to a wiki page that describes *the exact way to do it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install [dotnet-cli](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dotnet-cli/), you could use `yaourt` that helps to build and install AUR packages.

You can proceed like this :

- Add to /etc/pacman.conf

  ```
  [archlinuxfr]  
  SigLevel = Never  
  Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
  ```
- Update `pacman` and install `yaourt`:

  ```
  sudo pacman -Sy yaourt
  ```
- Next install dotnet-cli using:

  ```
  yaourt dotnet-cli
  ```

And follow the instruction of yaourt.

Comment: The archlinux.fr is a terrible idea; OP needs to actually *understand* what they are doing. Recommending a broken repo and an insecure package manager (yaourt) is doing them no favours.

Comment: @jasonwryan What's wrong ? yaourt just script the steps described in the AUR wiki, you can edit the PKGBUILD.

Comment: Read the [comparison table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table) on the wiki (hint: if it is all red, it is bad)...

Answer (score 8):

Edit: Please see [sunspots answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426669/220340) if you want to use Dot Net now because it is in the repositories now. This answer was written when it was not yet.

There are several packages pertaining to DotNetCore in the Archlinux User Repository (AUR). As noted in the answer by mpromonet, one of those is dotnet-cli. However, there is no need to install yaourt (or any other AUR helper) to install packages from AUR.

I know this will probably be too late for the OP, but for the sake of completeness, theses are the steps to install a package that is only in the AUR in Archlinux (or its derivates) without additional tools:

```
1) Make sure you have the base-devel group installed
2) Go to the website https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ and search the package
3) On the page for that package, klick "Download snapshot" and save the package to your computer
4) Extract the package on your computer: tar xvf <package_name>.tar.gz
5) cd <package_name>
6) makepkg
7) If the build fails, saying that a dependency is not satisfied, download and install that dependency first: try pacman -S <dependency> or else follow these steps
8) When the build succeeded, install the package:
   sudo pacman -U <pkgname>-<version_number>.tar.xz
```

See also the AUR [entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) in the Archlinux wiki for a more in-depth description of the AUR.

Comment: AUR doesn't hold packages. It's a buildscript repository. The packages are usually sourced  from their upstream on the fly while building.

Answer (score 4):

The packages for .NET Core are now available from the official Community repository.

If you only want to run .NET Core applications, you will need the [`dotnet-runtime`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=dotnet-runtime) package.

```
pacman -S dotnet-runtime
```

In case you also want to build .NET Core applications yourself, you need the [`dotnet-sdk`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=dotnet-sdk) package.

```
pacman -S dotnet-sdk
```